# How to use wordpress with MSSQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, wordpress, content-management-system

My company has a portal based on C# ASP.NET. I have to develop wordpress websites whose data is required to be driven from portal database i-e; MSSQL Server. There is no direct and simple solution to connect wordpress website with MSSQL. There is a project called [Project Nami](http://projectnami.org) which can help in this regard but is there any other way to achieve this objective? Is there any other CMS that can work like Wordpress and can run with MSSQL Server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: You can't. Try SQL CMS  instead.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is tightly coupled to MySQL. 
It can't be done and no amount of wishing otherwise by you, your business, or your management will change that.

You can deploy Wordpress as part of a website though with a separate MySQL somewhere but I would typically consider a separate URL (**blog**.mywebsite.com) and hosting it elsewhere. And uploading articles into this WP.

If MSSQL is 100% required for your articles, then you can't use WP. And I'd ask why, because clearly the presentation can be done elsewhere in this case and WP is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers above are incorrect. Of course you can connect php app, which is what wordpress is, to a mssql database. Microsoft has long ago provided the drivers for it. Google it and you will find drivers for linux or debian OS's.  It all depends on what you want to do. You will have to write your own code to pull the data you want from your mssql database and load it to wordpress to display it on the wp site. But saying php cannot connect to mssql is incorrect. Any php app can connect and grab data from MSsql database.